# MatSnackBar Content (Blazor) Not updating

Tags: c#, blazor, matblazor

I have seen this question, but it doesn't really get answered:
[MatSnackbar not updating MatSnackBarContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476465/matsnackbar-not-updating-matsnackbarcontent/58489299#58489299)
I have a similar issue and I wanted to see if anyone knows a solution.

I have a simple example:

```
     <div>Snackbar Status Message =  @StatusMessage</div>  <<< This shows the actual value
    
    <MatSnackbar @bind-IsOpen="@statusBarIsOpen">
        <MatSnackbarContent   >@StatusMessage</MatSnackbarContent>   <<< This should show the same
    </MatSnackbar>
```

I am updating the @StatusMessage by a custom event callback on a user form, and want to show the success or not of the update. (Quite a common use case I would have imagined?)

```
    // This is the callback handler for the 'OnUserSaved' callback
    protected void UserSaved(string statusmessage)
    {
        StatusMessage = statusmessage;     <<< Update the status message
        statusBarIsOpen = true;            <<< Open the snackBar / status bar
        this.StateHasChanged();            <<< fire the changed event
        isOpened = false;                  <<< this closes the form
    }
```

The first time, the StatusMessage is rendered correctly. After that it just stays fixed at the first message. While the  above correctly shows the status. I mean yes I could just use the line above and clear it etc.. but then, what is MatSnackBar for?
Is there some clear function I am missing, or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: So is that callback thread-safe?  This question is not self contained. Add a button to call UserSaved(), see if that works.

Comment: I'll give it a go in the morning, but given that the <div>Status Message etc.. binds perfectly well I am not optimistic... hope I have to eat words...

Comment: I don't know these components, but my feeling is that because you are not changing any public Parameters on the MatSnackBar then Blazor doesn't know it needs to render. You could test this simply by using `<MatSnackBarContent ChildContent=@StatusMessage />` instead. If that still doesn't work, try something like `<MatSnackBarContent data-message=@StatusMessage >@StatusMessage</MatSnackBarContent>`. "data-message" is just made up but because the base component accepts attribute splatting, it should see this as a reason to render.

Comment: I'll give that a try in the morning too. But as per the the previous question I refe referenced re this topic, I change the the value of the message before invoking the snack bar render... the Childcontent might do it though, I'll have a look. I guess I was hoping someone who had contributed to the matblazor might know. If these ideas dont work maybe I'll raise it on GitHub ... thanks..

Comment: I had a look at their code - there's nothing they can do really - it's about how the Blazor rendering code works - when you invoke StateHasChanged on your component/page, it queues up a render, but because there are no parameters changing on the snack bar component, it will flag that as unchanged. You have to make the renderer see that it should re-render the snack bar somehow - adding that fake attribute and assigning your status message to it should do that.

Comment: I tried the things you suggested and none of them really work. The ChildContent expects a RenderFragment object type which is even more hoops. I tried replacing it with a function call to get the string, that didnt work. Adding the fake attribute didnt work either I'm afraid...

Comment: I did find a solution though, I have tried a different library 'Blazorise'. That obviously works differently and has 'show' and 'hide' functions. So by using an @ref=snackbar, it is trivial to call snackbar.Show() in my UserSaved function.
I am going to keep both libs in for now and see how I go. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe use another library? like https://mudblazor.com

Answer (score 1):

A [solution](https://github.com/SamProf/MatBlazor/issues/652#issuecomment-663382575) on github solved with this workaround:

```
@if(@statusBarIsOpen)
{
    <MatSnackbar @bind-IsOpen="@statusBarIsOpen">
        <MatSnackbarContent>@StatusMessage</MatSnackbarContent>
    </MatSnackbar>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought. As I mentioned above I switched to Blazorise for now, which overall seems to fit a bit better with the c# in browser 'feel' for me anyway. Thanks again.